# When I say position:fixed, how do I tell mobile browsers I mean it?

Tags: css, mobile, orientation

I want to add a notice to the top of my page that appears when the browser:

- Supports media queries
- Is in portrait orientation
- Is too narrow for portrait orientation to work

To this end, I have an element `#portrait_alert` with the following CSS:

```css
#portrait_alert {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    font-size:8pt;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    /* a few more styles such as background, text color, etc. */
}
@media all and (orientation:portrait) and (max-width:500px) {
    #portrait_alert {display:block}
}
```

It works just fine when I test it on my desktop and change the window size to be taller than it is wide, and less then 500px wide. However, on a mobile browser the `right:0` seems to only apply to the initial viewport. When I scale the view down it leaves a gap to the right, and when I scale up it overflows the screen so you can't read it.

How can I fix this?

(Bonus question: Why can I still zoom out when I specify `minimum-scale=1.0`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot trap the zoom activity of the mobile browser like you can with window.resize or even css width and height.  The reason is the viewport is still x pixels wide, it's just zoomed in, not larger or smaller.  If someone sooms in or out, all of the elements on the page stay as they were originally loaded.  The reason for this is they don't want programmers to change the elements on a page when a user zooms in, e.g. resizing the text, because that could possibly negate the reason a user zoomed in the first place.  The user wanted to zoom in on your text and when they zoom you keep resizing the text, could be annoying right?

Try jquery mobile, sencha touch, jqmobi, etc.  These frameworks have prebuilt fixed position headers and footers.  here is an example http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html